# Setting the value of a GridEditableEitem

Tags: vb.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a `RadGrid` on which I'm doing validation of inserted/edited records. I get the existing values, if any, with `SavedOldValues` and the edited ones with `OwnerTableView.ExtractValuesFromItem` so I can perform the validation.

But for one particular field, if the value is below a certain threshold, or blank, then I want to change it to the minimum, with no need to tell the user. How can I do that?

I'm using this code:

```
Dim item As GridEditableItem = e.Item, values As New Hashtable 'e is from GridCommandEventArgs
rgRadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExtractValuesFromItem(values, item)
Dim w As Integer
If Not Integer.TryParse(values("Weight"), w) Then
    w = 0
End If
If w < minWeight Then item.[what do I put here?] = minWeight.ToString
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I have found is apparently no answer exists. This I have found from this page: https://www.telerik.com/forums/grideditableitem-updatevalues-problem-with-gridmaskedcolumn

It specifically says:

> You can not directly change the value.

So even trying to use `item.UpdateValues(values)`, which doesn't seem to do anything at all, the textbox values remain unchanged.

I'm solving my specific problem in an unsatisfactory, yet workable, way: passing my single updated value I want to check to the validation code. This would suck to use if I had to allow prior editing of any of the other fields to check, but in my case I don't. If I did, I suppose I could pass an additional object with all of the potentially edited values in them, but it seems like an unnecessary variable, only needed because I can't edit the `GridEditableItem` itself.

So my updated code simply passes `w` to the `ValidateRouteInfo` method I had. I also had to add this unnecessary variable to the Edit method which also calls `ValidateRouteInfo`, and put in the edited weight.